# Is it possible to push metrics to a grafana agent from a java application with OpenTelemetry agent instrumentation?

Tags: grafana, open-telemetry, grafana-agent

When I'm setting up my Grafana Agent, I see only the "scraping" option, so the agent itself needs to poll my java app (e.g. `/actuator/metrics` endpoint). I'm wondering if it's possible to have the "push" approach instead.

Basically, I want the same as we could do to collect traces: add otlp java agent to our application, set a grpc/http receiver on the agent side and that's it. But it seems that you cannot have `receivers` block for `metrics` section (which exists in `traces` section).

I'm using Grafana Agent v0.31 if it matters.

Comment: Try to enable trace receiver and push it there. It should work from the OTEL perspective. Question is how it is implemenet in the Grafana agent. You can switch to OTEL collector in the worst case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my research it seems it is not currently possible with "standard" Grafana Agent configuration.

It is possible to configure metrics receiver in OpenTelemetry Collector though.

Grafana has introduced [Grafana-Agent-Flow](https://grafana.com/docs/agent/latest/flow/getting_started/), which provides [OTelCollector components](https://grafana.com/docs/agent/latest/flow/reference/components/otelcol.receiver.prometheus/).

It seems like it would meet your requirements, however, as it is currently under heavy development and mentioned components are in BETA, I am not comfortable recommending it for production maintenance.

Comment: Exactly. I also got [an answer](https://github.com/grafana/agent/issues/3015#issuecomment-1435061975) from one of grafana agent developers with the sample flow configuration